# Sql query didn't get proper payment method

Tags: mysql, sql

I got issue while i execute my sql query with paymentmethod 1 show it's show paymentmethod 3 also. Please Check where i am wrong. Thanks in advance

[image: Image From phpmyadmin with access sql query.]

This is my sql query:-

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(u.`upperuserid`) 
         FROM user u 
         WHERE u.upperuserid = user.usernewid 
     ) as ref,
       usernewid,
       user.paymentmethod,usersecond, mod_date
from user 
HAVING ref <  2 or user.usersecond=0 and paymentmethod = 1
```

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need parentheses.  Your condition is evaluated as:

```
HAVING (ref <  2) or (user.usersecond = 0 and paymentmethod = 1)
```

Presumably you want:

```
HAVING (ref <  2 or user.usersecond = 0) and paymentmethod = 1
```

If you are mixing `and` and `or` in conditions, always use parentheses.

Comment: Awesome Work like a charm. :) will you please tell me where i am wrong ??

Answer (score 9):

```
ref <  2 or user.usersecond=0 and paymentmethod = 1
```

[Operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html).  This is being interpreted as:

```
(ref <  2) or (user.usersecond=0 and paymentmethod = 1)
```

Since the records in question match `ref < 2`, they are returned.

Explicitly define the precedence of your logic by grouping expressions in parentheses:

```
(ref <  2 or user.usersecond=0) and (paymentmethod = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks David for your Answer But Gordon Linoff 2 minutes before from your answer so that's why i accept his answer. am sorry and Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @kannu: I think the window was considerably closer than that, by seconds even.  Doesn't matter who gets votes/points though, what's important is that the question has useful information.  Glad we could help!